# Dynamic changing of ui-sref attribute in ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have issue with dynamic changing ui-sref.
I'm change ui-sref attr but when click on link with updated ui-sref it redirect to old state that was defined on this link.

It's look like it bind data at init and after changing **ui-sref** attr nothing changed.

```
<a  href="" ui-sref="{{navigatorNames.previous.stateName}}" >{{navigatorNames.previous.title}}</a> |
<a  href="" ui-sref="{{navigatorNames.current.stateName}}">{{navigatorNames.current.title}}</a> |
<a  href="" ui-sref="{{navigatorNames.next.stateName}}" >{{navigatorNames.next.title}}</a>
```

full code here 
http://plnkr.co/edit/qrDPBE?p=info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's look like it bind data at init and after changing ui-sref attr
>   nothing changed.

You are right, I think this is the way it is designed.

You can check this github post, people are talking about issues which are quite close to yours I think:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/395

Some of them just solved the problem by updating angular and ui-router.